# Como manter o layout em modo de espera?

Tags: java, android, xml

Bom tenho dois layout teste_1 e layout teste_2 , quando viro aparelho para retrato aparece teste_1 e quando viro aparelho para paisagem aparece teste_2, tem como deixar esse layout em modo de espera (inativo) para que seu dados não seja reiniciado quando mudar a orientação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar o atributo `android:configChanges="orientation"` dentro da tag `<activity>`  no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Essa configuração faz com que, ao invés de recriar a `Activity` ao mudar de orientação/configuração, sua `Activity` irá ter um callback (`onConfigurationChanged`, caso precise) no lugar.

Comment: não deu certo cai no mesmo problema da pergunta anterior, você poderia dar um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso no `AndroidManifest.xml` , dentro da `<activity`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|navigation|keyboard"
```